# Get high and low of previous condition candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to figure out how to get the high and low of the most recent previous candle that meets one of my conditions. I know to get a prior candles high you can use the [1], but if I do not know the number of how far back the previous candle is, how can I approach this?

high and low of most recent candle that has met condition

I have tried to use the calling prior data function with brackets, however, the problem is I am unaware as to how far back the last occurrence of the condition being met is, and it is always changing so I can not have a static number inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your condition is met, you should record the bar_index :

```
if myconditionismet then
    BarIndexWhenConditionIsMet := bar_index
```

Then you can use **BarIndexWhenConditionIsMet** to retrieve the high and the low your are looking for.